# Show that $f$ is $\mathbf{X}$-measurable iff $f^{-1}(E)\in\mathbf{X}$ for every Borel set $E$.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions

I'm trying to do exercises $2.N.$, $2.O.$, and $2.P.$ from Chapter $2$ of Bartle's The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure.

[image]

Here **X** is the $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

I already did the exercise $2.N$. Now I'm trying to do the exercises  $2.O.$ and $2.P.$. But I'm not understanding a passage in exercise $2.O.$:

> Let $A$ ( or **A**?) be a collection of subsets of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(E)\in$ **X** for every $E\in A$ (or $E\in$ **A**??).

The notation for $\sigma$-algebra that Bartle has adopted causes a lot of confusion.

I think it is important to solve exercise $2.O.$ because I think I will use it to solve the exercise $2.P.$.

Comment: 2.N follows directly from definition bearing in mind that $f^{-1}(\cap \mathrm{I}_\alpha) = \cap f^{-1}(\mathrm{I}_\alpha),$ $f^{-1}(\cup \mathrm{I}_\alpha) = \cup f^{-1}(\mathrm{I}_\alpha)$  and $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Y} \setminus \mathrm{I}) = \mathrm{X} \setminus f^{-1}(\mathrm{I}).$

2.O and 2.P follows instantly from 2.N (for 2.P recall the intervals generate the sigma algebra of Borel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion I denote collections of sets by curly letters.

By 2.N, $\mathcal{Y}=\{E\subset Y:f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{X}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, which contains $\mathcal{A}$ (because $f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{X}$ for all $E\in \mathcal{A}$). Therefore, it contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ (which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$).

According to Defintion 2.3 on page 8, for 2.P, take $\mathcal{A}=\{(\alpha,\infty):\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and note that $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: But what's $\mathcal{A}$? $\mathcal{A}=\{E\subset Y: f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{X}, E\in\mathcal{A}\}$? This doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. $\mathcal{A}$ is a subcollection among all subcollections of $\mathcal{Y}$. For example,  if $f$ is $\mathcal{X}$-measurable then $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty))$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{K} = \{(\alpha,+\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}:\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$. So by $2.N.$ and $2.O.$, $\mathcal{K}$ is a subcolection of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{R}=\{E\subset\mathbb{R}:f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{X}\}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{K})\subset\mathcal{R}$. But $\sigma(\mathcal{K})=\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Therefore, for every $E\in\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}\subset\mathcal{R}$ we have $f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{X}$. This proves the implication $\Rightarrow$ of question $2.P.$.